# Can ManagementScope be used to send wbem queries to Linux / MacOS clients from Windows? C#

Tags: c#, linux, macos, wmi, wbem

I'm currenty using C# and ManagementScope to connect to and run WMI queries on Windows machines on my network, and got this to work.

What I was wondering, and had some trouble finding information about, was if ManagementScope could be used to run WBEM queries on machines running Linux / MacOS? If not, what would I need to do to connect to Linux / MacOS clients from a Windows machine?

Mainly I want the query to return the machine's operating system and running processes. On Windows, this can be found in the WMI classes Win32_OperatingSystem and Win32_Process. What would be the equivalents in Linux/MacOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need to have a server first on the Linux machine? e.g. one of those listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management#Implementations

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697464/how-to-list-linux-running-process-from-c-net-client). I have even tried [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/%5Bc-%5D-get-process-id-pid-676244/) and it worked.

Also do you have admin rights on the remote server i.e Linux server?

Comment: These are ways to get the process list, but not sending WBEM queries to Linux.